# Listing Movies + Their Posters

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, html-table

I'm making a sample site where I must use JavaScript code for creating a table with five movie titles and posters. I'm a bit stuck -- I can make a table using HTML -- but how do I make a table in Javascript to display the movies? I also have to include the poster for each movie and use *forms* & *elements* arrays.

So far, I have the starting html page (start.html), where the user clicks a button. When they click the "yes" button, it jumps to movies.html where the Javascript table should be displayed.

**start.html**

```html
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <body>

      <h1> Do You Like Action Movies?</h1>



<button id="yesButton" class="float-left submit-button" >Yes</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("yesButton").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "actionmovies.html";
    };
</script>





</body>
</html>
```

**movies.html**

```html
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body>



My 5 Favorite Action Movies
<table border ="5">
 <tr>
 <th>Rank</th><th>Name of the movie</th><th>Poster</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>1</td><td>Titanic</td><th><img src="titanic_poster.jpg" alt="Titanic" height="50" width="50" ></th>



 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>2</td><td>Jurassic Park</td><th><img src="park.jpg" alt="Park"height="15" width="15"></th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>3</td><td>WestWorld</td><th><img src="park.jpg" alt="Park"height="15" width="15"></th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>4</td><td>Alien</td><th><img src="park.jpg" alt="Park"height="15" width="15"></th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>4</td><td>Terminator</td><th><img src="park.jpg" alt="Park"height="15" width="15"></th>
  
 </tr>
 </table>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean when user click on "yes" button, the move table shown on the same page?

Comment: it can be shown on the same page or displayed on a new one (dosent matter)

Comment: In fact, I don't understand what do you mean "how do I convert/change the code to JS?". In addition, why do you want to do that?

Comment: my instructions are to include JavaScript code for creating the table with five movie titles and posters

Comment: What is the data source (i.e. movie titles, poster image file name)?
From server? Or just store in an array?

Comment: the poster images will be stored on a server. The movie title names should be stored in an array

Comment: i also edited the question if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I just give you a sample code for your reference:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script type="javascript">
         var movieInfo=new Array();
         movieInfo["Titanic"]="titanic_poster.jpg";
         movieInfo["Jurassic Park"]="park.jpg";
function showMovieInfo()
{
    var result=$("#result");
    var table=document.createElement("table");
    table.style.border="5";
    result.empty();
    result.html("My 5 Favorite Action Movies");
    for (var key in movieInfo)
    {
      row=table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
        cell=row.insertCell(row.cells.length);
        cell.innerHTML=key;
        img=document.createElement("img");
        img.src=movieInfo[key];
        cell=document.createElement("th");
        cell.appendChild(img);
        row.appendChild(cell); 
    }
    result.append(table);
}

    </script>   
</head>
<body>

  <h1> Do You Like Action Movies?</h1>

 <button id="yesButton" class="float-left submit-button" onclick="showMovieInfo()">Yes</button>

  <div id="result">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following demo will create a `<table>` with 2 rows and 5 columns. I know you require 5 rows and 2 columns but I did it intentionally so you can learn how a "for" loop works. Pay special attention to the HTML because it's HTML5. The first 3 lines of your HTML is HTML4 and I think XML. There is a ton of things you should know, if this is a homework assignment and you are paying for this course, get your money back.

#### References

[**"for" loops**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement)

[**createElement()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

[**appendChild()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

[**insertRow()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow)

[**insertCell()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell)

[**innerHTML**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

[**Template Literals**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

**Details commented in Demo**

### Demo

```js
/* Array of movie titles
|| Each title is a string, all strings are wrapped in quotes or
|| backticks (ex. "string", 'string', or `string`)
|| Each string must be delimited by a comma
*/
var titles = ["Pulp Fiction", "300", "Matrix", "Fight Club", "Saving Private Ryan"];

/* Array of movie posters
|| Each poster is a string of a url of an image
*/
var posters = ['http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRz_2nKTNlxhVtzbh29kgL3m2ebLv3TlYyzrbyqBtEUxt6mBuZ-', 'http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTBzEJIRKwczo3BJhL94O9uTH-WptCG23FPKFX8KCNpbEyPuYWR', 'http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQq3pIz-aKgkmYX1dJ-EL-AlHSPcOO7wdqRIJ5gJy9qNinXpmle', 'http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRo6_dvAhH0Q-gebUiYJVsZLj3eZuLoDsUrhK_T0dGe9EcTgcPL', 'http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR0lDhR_dXAKTm9wysp3nWu6kP0V5skJBVbCNC_Q8urAWcr4iF_'];

// Create a <table> tag
var table = document.createElement('table');

// Add that <table> tag to the <body>
document.body.appendChild(table);

/* 2 "for" loops
|| 1st loop will insert a <tr> into <table> - 2 times
|| 2nd loop will insert a <td> into <tr> - 5 times for each <tr> 
*/
/* Start i at 0; stop after the 2nd loop; increment i by 1
|| Before this loop goes on to the next loop...
*/
for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  // Insert <tr> into <table>
  var row = table.insertRow();
  
  /* ...it must go and do 5 loops here
  || Start j at 0; stop after the 5th loop; increment j by 1
  */
  for (let j = 0; j < titles.length; j++) {
    // Insert a <td> into <tr>
    var cell = row.insertCell();
    /* if this is the 1st <tr> then add a title from the 
    || titles array 
    || This will be done 5 times once for each <td>
    */
    if (i === 0) {
      cell.innerHTML = titles[j];
      
    /* Otherwise (This is the for the 2nd <tr>)
    || Parse a string (a special string called Template Literal)
    || into HTML and add a different url from the posters array
    || for the last 5 loops
    */
    } else {
      cell.innerHTML = `<img src="${posters[j]}" width="50">`;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 70px
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <style>
    <!--CSS can go here-->
  </style>
</head>

<body>


  <script>
    <!--JavaScript can go here-->
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```